# Regex in nginx config location

Tags: nginx-config, nginx-location

Help how to correctly compose a regex for this nginx configuration

```
location ~ /handler1/(?<var1>.*) {
    proxy_pass        http://www.test.com/handler1/$var1;
}    

location ~ /handler1/(?<var1>.*)/handler2 {
    proxy_pass        http://www.test.com/handler1/$var1/handler2;
}

location ~ /handler1/(?<var1>.*)/handler2/(?<var2>.*)/handler3 {
    proxy_pass        http://www.test.com/handler1/$var1/handler2/$var2/handler3;
}
```

I tried different options but always hit the first match
I use this service https://nginx.viraptor.info/ to check the config
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPigZ.png)

Comment: What exactly do you want to match from your sample input?

Comment: I need to proxy the request to a specific url, but I always hit the first match

Comment: @Bohemian I added more information to the post

Comment: The problem is that `/handler1/(?<var1>.*)` will match ANYTHING that contains `/handler1/` so `var1` will be `asd2/handler2` for example.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I understand that this is the problem. But I can't find how to solve it

Comment: You need to reverse the location regexes so the more specific ones come first.  According to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-location-directive "the location with regular expressions are checked in order of their declaration in the configuration file. NGINX will run through the following steps to select a location block against a requested URI."

Comment: @JerryJeremiah omg i'm stupid
I tried a lot of things, and the solution was very simple.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `/handler1/(?<var1>.*)` will match ANYTHING that contains `/handler1/` so var1 will be `asd2/handler2` in your example.  You need to reverse the location regexes so the more specific ones come first.  So this will work:

```
server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
 access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

    location ~ /handler1/(?<var1>.*)/handler2/(?<var2>.*)/handler3 {
        proxy_pass        http://www.test.com/handler1/$var1/handler2/$var2/handler3;
    }

    location ~ /handler1/(?<var1>.*)/handler2 {
        proxy_pass        http://www.test.com/handler1/$var1/handler2;
    }

    location ~ /handler1/(?<var1>.*) {
        proxy_pass        http://www.test.com/handler1/$var1;
    }    
}
```

The secret is:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-location-directive

> To find a location match for an URI, NGINX first scans the locations that is defined using the prefix strings (without regular expression). Thereafter, the location with regular expressions are checked in order of their declaration in the configuration file.